# Is it possible to use Litmus to test kafka

Tags: kubernetes, automated-tests, chaos, openebs

Is it possible to use Litmus to test kafka? 
basically some test to figure out what happens in various scenarios. Initial thoughts are:

- deploying confluent helm chart for kafka and checking brokers gets Storage bound successfully
- Kill broker and ensure it comes back
- kill zookeeper pod and ensure it comes back
- kill consumer pods (my own apps) and ensure they come a back and doesn't miss message
- kill producer pod and ensure it comes back and ensure all messages get sent.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean a Litmus test as in a mini chaos engineering test and I'm also assuming that you mean to do in Kubernetes. Yes, you should be able to do as long as you have all your pods defined in a higher level abstraction like a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/), and [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) that inherently creates a [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/).

In the Kubernetes world to force this test you can just delete the pod where your Kafka/Zookeeper workload is running and they should be brought up by the ReplicaSet on to of your pods.

Comment: I think my question need some more Update. I am looking OpenEBS Litmus which is chaos engineering for stateful workloads on Kubernetes.

Comment: This question is a bit old but if someone stumbles on it here is a great getting started post with Kafka and litmus: https://dev.to/kondareddy103/kafka-chaos-engineering-with-litmus-fng . This is also a good getting started guide with litmus and chaos experiments with other platforms: https://github.com/ari-hacks/kubernetes-chaos-sandbox